# How to get aggregate of data from multiple dates in pandas?

Tags: python, pandas

I have the following data

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

df = pd.DataFrame(data={'name':['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f'],
                        'vaccine_1':['2021-01-20', '2021-01-20', '2021-02-20', np.nan, '2021-02-22', '2021-02-23'],
                        'vaccine_2':['2021-02-22', '2021-02-22', '2021-02-25', np.nan, '2021-03-22', np.nan]})

df['vaccine_1'] = pd.to_datetime(df['vaccine_1']).dt.date
df['vaccine_2'] = pd.to_datetime(df['vaccine_2']).dt.date
df
```

I want to convert the table into something like this

| date | vaccine_1_total | vaccine_2_total |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 2021-01-20 | 2 | 0 |
| 2021-02-20 | 1 | 0 |
| 2021-02-22 | 1 | 3 |
| 2021-02-25 | 0 | 0 |
| 2021-03-22 | 0 | 1 |

Basically I want to get the aggregate from each date to get how many people get the vaccine in certain dates, but since there are two dates there, I am lost.

A simple groupby doesn't give me the result.

```
df.groupby(['vaccine_1'])['name'].count()
```

The code only gives me the number of people vaccinated for the first time, I can't obtain the second one. How do I solve this? Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We can first melt the dataframe using [`DataFrame.melt`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.melt.html) then use [`pd.crosstab`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.crosstab.html)

```
out = df.filter(like='vaccine').melt(var_name='vaccine', value_name='date')
print(pd.crosstab(out['date'], out['vaccine']))

vaccine     vaccine_1  vaccine_2
date                            
2021-01-20          2          0
2021-02-20          1          0
2021-02-22          1          2
2021-02-23          1          0
2021-02-25          0          1
2021-03-22          0          1
```

Comment: ok thanks, can I ask something? what if I also have other columns that need the same treatment like 'vaccine_type', 'vaccination_location'? Is it possible to do multiple 'melt'? Or should I use a whole different code for that?

Comment: @catris25 Yes you can melt multiple columns. Checkout `value_vars`argument in [`df.melt`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.melt.html#pandas.melt), just pass the list of columns you want to melt. `df.melt(value_vars= your_list)`.

Answer (score 1):

Count each `vaccine` column separately:

```
(df.filter(like='vaccine')
   .apply(pd.Series.value_counts)
   .fillna(0)
   .add_suffix('_total')
   .rename_axis('date')
   .reset_index())

         date  vaccine_1_total  vaccine_2_total
0  2021-01-20              2.0              0.0
1  2021-02-20              1.0              0.0
2  2021-02-22              1.0              2.0
3  2021-02-23              1.0              0.0
4  2021-02-25              0.0              1.0
5  2021-03-22              0.0              1.0
```

Answer (score 1):

You could do a melt, get the value counts, then unstack to put the vaccines as headers:

```
 (df.melt('name', value_name = 'Date')
    .drop(columns='name')
    .value_counts()
    .unstack('variable', fill_value=0)
    .add_suffix('_total')
     # last two not necessary
     # indexes are a good thing
    .rename_axis(columns=None)
    .reset_index()
  )

              vaccine_1_total  vaccine_2_total
Date
2021-01-20                2                0
2021-02-20                1                0
2021-02-22                1                2
2021-02-23                1                0
2021-02-25                0                1
2021-03-22                0                1
```