# How to aggregate multiple columns in pandas?

Tags: python, pandas

I have previously asked a similar question here
[How to get aggregate of data from multiple dates in pandas?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69008130/how-to-get-aggregate-of-data-from-multiple-dates-in-pandas/)

But my problem is slightly more complicated.

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

df = pd.DataFrame(data={'name':['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f'],
                        'vaccine_1':['2021-01-20', '2021-01-20', '2021-02-20', np.nan, '2021-02-22', '2021-02-23'],
                        'vaccine_2':['2021-02-22', '2021-02-22', '2021-02-25', np.nan, '2021-03-22', np.nan], 
                        'vaccine_type': ['AZ', 'AZ', 'AZ', np.nan, 'Sinovac', 'Sinovac'],
                        'gender':['F', 'M', 'F', 'F', 'M', 'M']})

df['vaccine_1'] = pd.to_datetime(df['vaccine_1']).dt.date
df['vaccine_2'] = pd.to_datetime(df['vaccine_2']).dt.date
df
```

I want to get a table that comprises something like this.

```
date | F | M | vaccine_type | vaccine_1_total | vaccine_2_total |
```

My original tables are way more complicated than this with more data, but I think sums up what I mean to do.

Thanks to the answers from my previous question, I can get the dates right using pandas melt.

```
out = df.melt(var_name='vaccine', value_name='date', value_vars=['vaccine_1', 'vaccine_2'])
print(pd.crosstab(out['date'], out['vaccine']))
```

Output:

```
vaccine     vaccine_1  vaccine_2
date 
2021-01-20          2          0
2021-02-20          1          0
2021-02-22          1          2
2021-02-23          1          0
2021-02-25          0          1
2021-03-22          0          1
```

But I don't know how to modify that to make it fit my needs. Any idea? Thanks.

EDIT:

Desired dataframe

```
date        | F | M | vaccine_type | vaccine_1_total | vaccine_2_total 
'2021-01-20'| 1 | 1 | AZ           | 2               | 0 
'2021-02-20'| 1 | 0 | AZ           | 1               | 0 
'2021-02-22'| 1 | 1 | AZ           | 1               | 1 
'2021-02-22'| 1 | 0 | Sinovac      | 1               | 0
```

and so on

So I think it should be a combination of groupby and melt? I can use groupby to get the non date columns, but how do I combine that with melt?

Comment: Please show a whole dataframe example for the desired output.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can first create a table with the combined counts for gender and vaccine_x, then merge on the sum on the different indicators:

```
df2 = (df.melt(id_vars=['gender', 'vaccine_type'],
               value_vars=['vaccine_1', 'vaccine_2'],
               var_name='vaccine', value_name='date')
         .groupby(['date', 'vaccine_type', 'gender']).agg({'vaccine': 'value_counts'})
         .rename(columns={'vaccine': 'count'})
         .reset_index()
         .pivot_table(index=['date', 'vaccine_type'], columns=['gender', 'vaccine'], values='count', fill_value=0)
        )

pd.merge(df2.sum(level=0, axis=1).reset_index(),
         df2.sum(level=1, axis=1).reset_index(),
         on=['date', 'vaccine_type']
        )
```

output:

```
         date vaccine_type  F  M  vaccine_1  vaccine_2
0  2021-01-20           AZ  1  1          2          0
1  2021-02-20           AZ  1  0          1          0
2  2021-02-22           AZ  1  1          0          2
3  2021-02-22      Sinovac  0  1          1          0
4  2021-02-23      Sinovac  0  1          1          0
5  2021-02-25           AZ  1  0          0          1
6  2021-03-22      Sinovac  0  1          0          1
```

intermediate output (df2):

```
gender                          F                   M          
vaccine                 vaccine_1 vaccine_2 vaccine_1 vaccine_2
date       vaccine_type                                        
2021-01-20 AZ                   1         0         1         0
2021-02-20 AZ                   1         0         0         0
2021-02-22 AZ                   0         1         0         1
           Sinovac              0         0         1         0
2021-02-23 Sinovac              0         0         1         0
2021-02-25 AZ                   0         1         0         0
2021-03-22 Sinovac              0         0         0         1
```

Comment: Interesting. I modified the code to fit my needs and it works. May I ask something? What does `pivot_table` do there?

Comment: It is to benefit from the `fill_value` option to fill with 0, but you can also use `pivot`+`fillna(0)`

Comment: I see, the `pivot_table` is there to break down the values of vaccine (sinovac, AZ) and gender (F,M). CMIIW. How about the `pd.merge`? What is it for?

Comment: this is to combine the two tables, one for the count per gender, the second for the count per vaccine dose